# Is the Left-Hand Operand First broken?

Tags: c#, operators, operator-precedence

According to [Precedence and order of evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx)
left will be evaluated before right. However, I have a project where:

```
int[] df = null;  //GetDataFrame()
int xIndex =  12; //GetLearningIndex()
df[0] = 1 % GetLearningIndex();
```

and I realized, when **GetDataFrame** returns **null** and **GetLearningIndex** returns zero I get an `System.DivideByZeroException` I would expect according to the like a `System.NullReferenceException` ...any reason why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some confusion here... *parts* of the LHS of the assignment operator are evaluated first. In particular, the expressions `df` and `0` will be evaluated *before* `GetLearningIndex`, but the array element assignment (including index validation) only occurs *after* the result has been calculated.

Here's an example showing some more details:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    private int[] array = new int[10];

    static void Main()
    {
        Test instance = null;

        // This would throw a NullReferenceException
        // because instance is null at the start of the statement.
        // ExecuteSideEffect never gets called.        
        // instance.array[100] = ExecuteSideEffect(() => instance = new Test());

        instance = new Test();

        // This would throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException
        // because instance.array is evaluated before ExecuteSideEffect.
        // The exception is only thrown when the assignment is performed.
        // instance.array[100] = ExecuteSideEffect(() => instance.array = new int[1000]);

        int index = 5;
        // This modifies array index 5 because index is evaluated
        // before EvaluateSideEffect
        instance.array[index] = ExecuteSideEffect(() => index = 1);
        Console.WriteLine(instance.array[5]); // 10
    }

    private static int ExecuteSideEffect(Action action)
    {
        action();
        return 10;
    }
}
```

So in a statement of this form:

```
arrayExpression[indexExpression] = valueExpression;
```

the execution order is:

1. Evaluate `arrayExpression`. There's no check that the result is non-null, but evaluating the expression may itself throw a `NullReferenceException`.
2. Evaluate `indexExpression`. No bounds check is performed on the array at this point.
3. Evaluate `valueExpression`
4. Set the array element expressed using the results of steps 1 and 2 to the result of step 3. *This* is where the checks that the array reference is non-null and the array index is valid are performed.

This is currently badly specified as far as I can tell - I'll raise an issue to see if we can fix it in the ECMA C# 5 standard.

Answer (score 4):

Left-hand operands are evaluated first when it comes to math operations. In your case, you are calling a method which returns a value: `GetLearningIndex()`, which value will always be evaluated before any math operation you use it with.

Comment: This is far from the whole story. The important part is which parts of `df[0]` are evaluated before the RHS is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You´re actually referring to the wrong document. As mentioned on [the actual one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) the assignment-operator *is* evaluated at last. Thus your method-call as well as the math-operation (`%` is evaluated before the assignment results in the `DivideByZeroException`.

Furthermore the assignment-operator is evaluated from right to left in contrast to all the other binary ones that are evaluated from left to right:

> Except for the assignment operators, all binary operators are
> left-associative, meaning that operations are performed from left to
> right. For example, x + y + z is evaluated as (x + y) + z. The
> assignment operators and the conditional operator (?:) are
> right-associative, meaning that operations are performed from right to
> left. For example, x = y = z is evaluated as x = (y = z).